# What is = Not(VB) in C#

Tags: c#, vb.net

So say if I have this code

```
circularProgress1.IsRunning = Not circularProgress1.IsRunning // in VB
```

how would I make this in C# ?

```
circularProgress1.IsRunning != circularProgress1.IsRunning // This doesn't work
```

Comment: What is "doesn't work"?

Comment: @zerkms I guess he means it doesn't work "as a synonym" of the above VB.NET expression, because it is not the "not" operator.

Comment: okay I had the ! on the wrong side thanks

Comment: @MethodManX No. You were using a binary operator which means "is different from" and has two characters, !=, instead of an assignment operator '=' followed by an unary operator which also has one character, '!', and means "not". You need to understand this and not just think that you had the characters misplaced, as if  it was a question of bad luck.

Answer (score 15):

```
circularProgress1.IsRunning = !circularProgress1.IsRunning;
```

[`=`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sbkb459w%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is an assignment and [`!`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f2kd6eb2%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is a negation

The [`!=`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/3tz250sf.aspx) operator is the opposite of the [`==`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/53k8ybth.aspx) operator. It returns `true` when two objects are unequal. Side-note: In VB.NET the assignement- and the equality-operator are both  `=`.

Comment: != is the boolean comparison of the two values.

Comment: @mfras3r: Edited my answer to give a more detailed answer.

Answer (score 2):

```
circularProgress1.IsRunning = !circularProgress1.IsRunning.
```